# Footer view for Listview is not showing on 1 device, but is on another?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, footer

I have a very odd problem i must admit.

I'm building an Android app with a Listview, and then i have a button to add a footer view on this listview (where you can type in some information needed to add an item to the list)

This is easily done, and 100% fully working on my own phone (Samsung Galaxy Note 2), but on my friends phone (Samsung Galaxy S2), the absolutely same application with the same code, when pressing the "Add footer" button, nothing shows up.
I've added log messages in the code when adding a footer view, and i can see the log messages printed out, so the code is actually being executed. But the footer view never shows up.

Everything else about the application is working fine.

Does anyone have any idea about this? I'm at a loss here :/

Comment: It could be the API version. Only debugging your code on your friends device will help.

Comment: You are probably using addFooterView, which adds a footer INSIDE the ListView. On a phone, the screen is notably smaller than on a tablet. Just SCROLL UP the ListView in the phone. If you want the footer to be always visible, then you should design your layout to have a footer view anchored to the parent's bottom and then place a ListView ABOVE it.

Answer (score 6):

at first add footer view, and after set adapter to list view

```
listView.addFooterView(footerView);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```